# Kenmore gas oven won't ignite

Tags: oven, stove

Kenmore 665.75132300 oven will not heat. The igniter will not light. Since the oven stopped working I have noticed then when you turn on the oven all four burners will click four times. The igniter will not light. The gas does kick on for about 5 seconds and then turns off. Not having a clue as to when I'm doing I did replace the igniter and I still have the same results. The new igniter does not light, four clicks from the burners the gas will turn on in the oven for 5 seconds and then the gas shuts off and nothing happens. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hopefully this is allowed, but I'd recommend posting here: https://forum.partsdr.com/

Answer (score 1):

If a furnace was exhibiting that behavior I'd assume a flame sensor was out. I don't believe your oven has a flame sensor, but it probably has a temperature sensor or other mechanism to make sure it doesn't fill your kitchen with gas. Investigating that would be my next step.